# Затруднения в реализации MVVM, возможные проблемы с LivaData

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, livedata

Первый раз пробую реализовать паттерн mvvm. Честно говоря идет со скрипом... Для начала опишу задачу: пишу приложение для вытягивания расписания, запросы генерирую с помощью okhttp3. Результаты запросов должны использоваться сразу на нескольких фрагментах, что привело меня к идеи использовать ViewModel, а отсюда желание написать все в mvvm.

Идея такая: я обращаюсь к ViewModel, если данные в ней есть - возвращаю их. Если данных нет - делаю асинхронный запрос за данными и возвращаю их. Идея взята с официальной документации. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как обновить данные во ViewModel после асинхронного запроса, точнее как это сделать правильно. Сейчас, при взятие данных из ViewModel я быстро получаю null, в то время как запрос за данными выполняется параллельно и вообще живет своей собственной жизнью. Я бы хотел, получать данные из ViewModel полностью инкапсулировав запросы за ViewModel. т.е. в самом приложении я запросы не шлю, а всегда обращаюсь к ViewModel, а уже она при необходимости шлет запросы к серверу.

Привожу свой код. Реализация пока черновая (советы и конструктивная критика с вашей стороны принимаются)

**ScheduleViewModel** - реализованная модель. При создании инициализируется класс-репозиторий.

```
class ScheduleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var repository: ScheduleRepository ?= null
    var schools: MutableList<School> ?= null
    var groupList: MutableList<Group> ?= null
    var week: LiveData<Week> ?= null

    fun init(apiClient: okhttp3.OkHttpClient, apiCall: Call?) {
        this.repository = ScheduleRepository(apiClient, apiCall)
    }

    fun getWeek(scheduleUrl: String) : LiveData<Week> {
        if(week == null)
            week = repository?.getWeek(scheduleUrl)

        return week as LiveData<Week>
    }
}
```

Класс-репозиторий **ScheduleRepository**

```
class ScheduleRepository(apiClient: okhttp3.OkHttpClient, apiCall: Call?) {
    private var requestHelper: RequestHelper = RequestHelper(apiClient, apiCall)

    fun getWeek(endOfUrl: String): LiveData<Week> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Week>()
        val scheduleUrl = "${RequestConfig.END_POINT_SCHEDULER}$endOfUrl"

        requestHelper.getRequest(scheduleUrl, object : NetworkFragment.ResponseHandling {
            override fun doHandling(bodyString: String) {
                val groupsListObj = getBuiltGsonInstance()
                        .fromJson(
                                JSONObject(bodyString).toString(),
                                RequltResultSchedule::class.java
                        )
                data.postValue(groupsListObj.week)
            }
        })

        return data
    }
}
```

Тело **RequestHelper** (для краткого ознакомления, сами запросы ходят хорошо, результаты возвращают):

```
 class RequestHelper(private val apiClient: okhttp3.OkHttpClient,
                    private var apiCall: Call?) {

    fun getRequest(url: String, successListener: NetworkFragment.ResponseHandling,
                   vararg urlParts: String) {

        val builder = HttpUrl.parse(url)!!.newBuilder()
        for(part in urlParts)
            builder.addPathSegment(part)

        val requestBuilder = Request.Builder()
                .url(builder.build())
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .get()

        apiCall = apiClient.newBuilder()
                .build()
                .newCall(requestBuilder.build())

        apiCall!!.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                // SERVER_ERROR
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response) {
                var bodyString: String? = null
                try {
                    bodyString = response.body()!!.string()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                if (response.code() == 204 || bodyString == null || !response.isSuccessful) {
//                    NOT_CONTENT
                    return
                }

                try {
                    successListener.doHandling(bodyString)

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
//                    BAD_REQUEST
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

А вот так я пробую взять данные из MainActivity:

```
viewModel.getWeek("24036?date=2018-5-21").observe(this, Observer { week ->
    Toast.makeText(this, "showLoading ${week?.days?.size}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
})
```

Мне интересно мнение специалистов: верно ли я проектирую архитектуру? Если да, как заставить модель ждать результата запроса из репозитория? Если нет, как правильно реализовать?

Вообщем как-то так..

Comment: Не понятно что значит "заставить модель ждать результата запроса из репозитория"? Если у вас ViewModel содержит LiveData, зачем ей что-то ждать?

Comment: Похоже в реализации ViewModel вы применяете подходы для работы с обычными данными, которые не работают для LiveData. Т.е. проблемы с паттерном нет, есть проблема с LiveData.

Comment: про какое именно место вы говорите?     if(week == null)
            week = repository?.getWeek(scheduleUrl)

        return week as LiveData<Week> ? В данном проекте я так же впервые использую LiveData. Пример как с ними работать я так же взял с гугл доков

Comment: В вашем случае смысл `var week: LiveData<Week>` теряется, т.к. вы ее после каждого запроса пересоздаете, а идея LiveData как раз в обратном, созданная единожды, данные в ней могут меняться, но сам обьект нет, потому что на него кто-то может быть подписан.

Comment: И второе, если данные могут быть за любую неделю, смысл в общей переменной, если и не узнать, что за неделя там?

Comment: объект Week сожержит порядка 50 переменных) В том числе начало и конец недели, а так ее порядковый номер. Полагаю, проблема которую вы описали имеет место быть. Первостепенная проблема в другом: я всегда вижу null, т.к. модель не ждет окончание запроса и сразу возвращает то что есть. Как заставить модель подписаться на окончание запроса?

Comment: Закрывайте этот и задавайте новый вопрос конкретно по LiveData.

Comment: вообще-то я это и спрашивал... Совет "по архитектуре" -  это мелкое дополнение. Спасибо что уделили мне свое время.

Answer (score 1):

Пару комментариев (опять же вкусовщина - но смотрите как рекомендует Google https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide):

- для модели нужный параметр сам репозиторий (а он уже знает что под низом)
- параметром модели я бы использовал дату и дни в (явно определив ее в доменной области) - сначала подписывался и потом бы делал setDate (которое бы вызывало либо отдачу из кэша или запрос к серверу)
- я бы использовал Retrofit и ему передавал параметры из модели

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ) "для модели нужный параметр сам репозиторий" - Репозиторий уже объявлен как параметр в моделе. JSON объект Week, который я вытягиваю с сервера включает не только дни и дату. Там так же есть преподаватели, аудитории, здания, номер недели и т.д. Я бы не хотел выносить их все в корень ViewModel. К ретрофиту я обязательно вернусь, но после того как отлажу обновление модели. Скажите, вы не знаете, как заставить модель ждать результата запроса из репозитория? У меня с этим сейчас некоторые затруднения)

Comment: Посмотрите - Google реокмендует вот такую обертку https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum т.е. по мере старта сразу кидается LiveData со статусом - Загрузка, Данные и ошибка.

Comment: Вот так работает последовательное кэширование в их версии https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/rc1/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.java